# Libraries in MFC and /clr C++ projects

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have a 3rd party library to speak to a piece of hardware. The vendor has provided a sample (VS) solution, a C++ MFC app that demonstrates the calls – this application runs fine on our machine. It calls an initialisation function, asks for a serial port HANDLE and then does some comms. All hunky dory.

When I link to the libraries from our own Hardware Comms C++ project (on the same machine with identical hardware), it compiles and links and runs ok, and the initialisation return value is "ok" and it has done at least something as the number of available serial ports is returned correctly.

But when I call the open serial port function with the parameter (uint) 2 (second of 6, definitely the correct one), I get back a NULL HANDLE. I have made the exact library calls the sample code makes in the same order but the sample code returns a non-NULL and hence usable HANDLE, and so can communicate.

I have no clue as to what the problem is. What is stopping me from moving incrementally away from something that works to something that doesn’t is that the sample code is an MFC exe (I have never used MFC) and our Hardware Comms C++ project is a dll with clr support.  There are masses of differences between the project settings and includes required in each, it seems to me. I have tried to use the existing code as a template for a new stand alone CLR project but it requires so many changes of project settings and include files that it barely seems comparable and I don’t want to keep fiddling around with this unless I can find some evidence that this might actually be the source of the problem.

So: I was provided with a solution with a single project – a C++ project with “Project Defaults” of:  Application.exe, Use MFC in Shared DLL, Not using ATL, Use Multi-byte Character Set, No Common Language Runtime Support, No Whole Program Optimization. This project uses the same library files I’ve been given (*.h, *.lib and dll) and produces an exe which gets back a non-NULL handle (and I’ve verified this directly in Debug) and so can communicate with the device.

The Hardware Comms Project in our application to speak to the other hardware has “Project Defaults” of:  Dynamic Library (.dll), Use Standard Windows Libraries, Not using ATL, Use Unicode Character Set, Common Language Runtime Support (/clr), No Whole Program Optimization.

My question is, is there any reason why these same library files won’t work when I reference them from our /clr Hardware Comms Project? That is, could the library have some ”memory” of it’s creation that means it will work with one but not the other (remembering that the code compiles and links and at least did *something* in that it returned true from the initialisation function and told me correctly there are 6 ports)? Or, given the library is working and communicating in the MFC app, does this mean I should be able to reference it from the clr project no problem and that we have some other cause for the NULL serial port problem (which is entirely possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actual code or lib is this just guessing question.

I am no VC/MFC user but I come across similar problems too:

1. **due to x86/x64 incompatibility?**

   Check if DLL and EXE are for the same platform both must be the same (x86 or x64) and also the exe using the DLL of course else HW stuff handling changes a lot due to WOW64 emulator (usually need some x64 hook). Also class **GUID**s can be different which I found with some USB drivers.
2. **Also check if COM classes aren't initialized/imported from lib more than once**

   it behaves similar too all functions are not NULL but find no real HW  just **NULL** handles. I found this problem with 'MS' Kinect driver which is JUNGO actually :)

Comment: Yes sorry, it is basically a "can anyone guess the answer" question. It is a question about the project settings and library usage - the C++ code in both versions is I believe, essentially, identical. I'll run through your suggestions now.

Comment: Went ahead and replicated the correct behaviour on a stand alone /clr app and so searched elsewhere. 

The (in retrospect, obvious) answer to the problem of why requesting a HANDLE returns 0 is that the port is already opened and in use by some other part of the discovery process. This proved to be the case - nothing whatsoever to do with MFC or /clr or anything.